# Javascript Regex and non-capturing parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm a bit rusty on my regexp and Javascript. I have the following string var:

```
var subject = "/admin.php?page=settings&tabs_added[114787535263592]=1&tabs_added[217770811582323]=1&tabs_added[198738186831542]=1"
```

I want to extract `114787535263592`, `217770811582323` and `198738186831542`.

I've tried to use non-capturing parenthesis `(?:)` :

```
var regexp = /(?:tabs_added[\[])(\d)+(?:[\]])/;
var pageid = regexp.exec(subject);
```

But the result I get (`["tabs_added[114787535263592]", "2"]`) is not what I expected -- what am I doing wrong? Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KgpAw/

Comment: Your `(?:)` group looks fine, but the `(?+)` looks fishy.

Comment: @andrewcooke Sorry about that, I messed up when pasting. It's a `?:`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You're totally right. I added a link to jsFiddle that shows what the result is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were very close. You need to capture the `+` as well. Otherwise you only capture one decimal digit:

```
var regexp = /(?:tabs_added[\[])(\
```

You should also make your regex global to find all matches:

```
var regexp = /(?:tabs_added[\[])(\d+)(?:[\]])/g;
```

Then you should loop through the results, you also don't need to have non-capturing groups because you're not using a quantifier on them (`?`, `+`, or `*`), nor do you need to put your `[` and `]` inside a character class:

```
var regexp = /tabs_added\[(\d+)\]/g;
var result;
while(null != (result = regexp.exec(subject))){
    document.write(result[1] + '<br />');
}
```

[**JSFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/KgpAw/2/)

Note: It's better to use `console.log` for debugging  purposes than `document.write` as long as you have a console available. (Chrome, Opera, IE9, and Firefox have consoles built in, and I think Safari does too, so you should have one available.) `console.log` provides much more valuable information when logging objects and arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You need global flag and match all digits: `(\d+)` instead of `(\d)+`.

And don't need all those non-capturing subgroups.

```
var regexp = /tabs_added\[(\d+)\]/g;
var pageIds = [], match;
while(match = re.exec(str)) pageIds.push(match[1]);
pageIds;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi i can solve above requirement in one line code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
var str="/admin.php?page=settings&tabs_added[114787535263592]=1&tabs_added[217770811582323]=1&tabs_added[198738186831542]=1"; 
var patt1=/\d{15}/g; 
document.write(str.match(patt1));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple matches, you need to use the g modifier. Please try the following

```
var regexp = /(?:tabs_added[\[])(\d)+(?:[\]])/g;
var pageid = subject.match(regexp);
```

This will still contain the tabs_added part, but that can be removed separately